# schedule a map reduce script progrmatically

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

Has anyone wrote any code to modify a script deployment through suitescript ?
I am trying to load and set the start date and start time for a map reduce script but its not working

```
var record2= nlapiLoadRecord('scriptdeployment', id, {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
record2.setFieldValue('status' , 'SCHEDULED');
record2.setFieldValue('startdate' , new Date());
record2.setFieldValue('starttime' , 1100);
nlapiSubmitRecord(record2,true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please be more specific.

Comment: meaning it wont allow me to set the start date and start time values of a map reduce script

Comment: since you can't do that direclty what are you tying to achieve by doing this in a map /reduce? Can't you just extend the reduce script to achieve whatever you wanted to do in the scheduled script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployment records are not scriptable.

Comment: Technically some of the fields are scriptable. For instance I use this to un-sechedule scripts in a console window in sandbox refreshes:
`nlapiSearchRecord('scriptdeployment', null, [
    ['script.scripttype', 'is', 'SCHEDULED'], 'AND', ['status', 'is', 'SCHEDULED']
], new nlobjSearchColumn('name', 'script')).forEach(function(ref) {
    var rec = nlapiLoadRecord(ref.getRecordType(), ref.getId());
    rec.setFieldValue('status', 'NOTSCHEDULED');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
});`

Netsuite just doesn't take the startdate and starttime

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the N/task module, to start a Map/Reduce script progammatically.

As for scheduling it you could just do that from the deployment record, or call the N/task module to start it from some other trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the start date field with a text value rather than Date object?

Usually a date object works for a date/time field.  Maybe you need to source the DATEFORMAT preference,  and set the date value accordingly.

The same would apply for the time field,  it should be in the same time string format as you see in the UI.

Comment: Nope that doesnt work i have tried that ... i actually just found that the starttime field is not scriptable only certain fields on that record are scriptable 
https://system.na2.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/script/record/scriptdeployment.html

https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_3753014009.html